# ARIMA forecast straight line?

Tags: forecasting, arima, prediction

I have daily mean temperature data with 856 observations, no missing data.

[image: Time Series daily temperature]

I used `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` package and got a ARIMA(1,1,2) model:

```
fit <- auto.arima(y, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE)
```

My goal is to predict daily temperature for a year or maybe even longer. It is really important to get differing trials/values every time I run the forecast, in order to get a distribution function at a given time. Someone suggested bootstrapping, but I don't know hot to use it....

Another problem is that I get a straight line and not a zig-zag when forecasting:

```
plot(forecast(fit, h=730))
```

[image: two year daily values forecast]

How can I solve this to get different values for every forecast and a nice zig-zag line?

Here is the data (the output of `dput(y)`):

```
structure(c(2.72107, 2.07831, 2.28904, 5.19602, 3.91104, 4.72452, 
  6.93097, 3.47825, 3.32989, 5.07382, 4.63729, 4.1209, 4.97381, 5.36145, 
  5.20141, 6.50965, 6.11698, 5.17949, 5.59227, 5.98244, 8.89354, 11.6026, 
  10.9734, 8.35629, 6.45573, 4.29485, 4.02906, 5.86246, 7.05204, 9.25902, 
  12.1916, 10.1092, 8.29306, 8.3226, 4.91195, 3.23493, 7.56046, 9.65728, 
  10.5852, 9.71882, 9.89834, 9.70065, 10.881, 7.94012, 7.96884, 6.76446, 
  5.87689, 7.42511, 7.23663, 6.88842, 7.46532, 8.28891, 9.98618, 12.8484, 
  15.0866, 16.1529, 12.998, 11.2972, 10.4044, 18.1593, 13.0845, 10.1179, 
  9.73825, 11.699, 13.7335, 15.8953, 12.2394, 14.6368, 17.3849, 17.7564, 
  16.4018, 13.3457, 10.1037, 11.9855, 13.6543, 12.8223, 12.7669, 14.8924, 
  20.8229, 20.9681, 19.4538, 15.8028, 16.2083, 18.5207, 13.8544, 16.5748, 
  19.8769, 13.0502, 14.1493, 17.4757, 13.4282, 13.626, 17.5759, 18.4219, 
  16.1828, 15.7175, 15.9433, 18.4769, 19.4068, 19.804, 15.0896, 13.0475, 
  16.2968, 18.4375, 15.5119, 18.3765, 16.6796, 20.6907, 21.1161, 20.6478, 
  23.9783, 26.679, 23.1433, 18.3136, 17.6282, 19.4527, 22.0328, 23.9067, 
  24.0465, 20.467, 18.9685, 15.6098, 18.9734, 18.469, 16.3081, 15.9136, 
  17.9241, 17.684, 13.4759, 15.3975, 20.9233, 21.5037, 21.2381, 21.6311, 
  24.0587, 25.0831, 24.6393, 26.3389, 29.1436, 31.3079, 30.4857, 24.8496, 
  27.8717, 21.693, 17.8961, 18.3907, 19.2113, 20.6967, 19.7234, 19.7314, 
  21.7928, 25.1407, 27.7266, 26.6256, 21.084, 23.1858, 26.1919, 27.907, 
  23.4193, 23.788, 24.127, 21.0114, 20.5417, 19.7877, 19.4958, 18.7987, 
  17.5373, 21.6209, 25.4621, 27.2367, 28.1586, 25.1398, 28.5401, 29.7519, 
  28.2289, 25.1979, 27.5075, 29.6323, 25.5448, 26.0691, 28.2604, 27.7191, 
  25.9823, 25.0804, 21.6709, 22.1457, 22.2224, 22.649, 22.6009, 21.5145, 
  23.8828, 21.0305, 22.9268, 22.7175, 19.8786, 21.2565, 24.217, 28.7001, 
  25.0747, 19.1498, 17.2221, 17.9607, 16.7414, 15.9127, 16.0407, 16.3318,       
  15.1847, 16.2885, 15.5795, 19.1367, 20.6138, 19.1671, 17.0597, 18.4442, 
  20.6328, 17.2387, 16.6262, 15.0164, 14.4777, 16.652, 15.549, 15.6622, 
  15.648, 15.0444, 14.024, 14.0647, 13.996, 13.5328, 12.3894, 12.6372, 
  14.004, 16.6147, 15.0356, 15.0433, 13.9245, 9.521, 10.2423, 7.6857, 
  6.44648, 5.79129, 5.81486, 6.62451, 7.66923, 9.49628, 9.68583, 10.2271, 
  9.55193, 10.9726, 11.18, 10.3731, 12.7261, 10.0939, 11.4238, 9.04498, 
  9.13095, 8.67738, 7.3758, 8.5583, 11.5121, 10.1994, 8.11629, 5.45508, 
  4.51418, 10.0511, 12.0646, 16.0265, 14.8723, 14.8256, 15.5313, 15.1156, 
  13.5751, 12.4647, 9.20753, 11.6803, 12.1874, 13.0886, 13.1678, 12.4585, 
  9.10043, 6.46029, 3.37006, 2.2908, 2.4312, 4.25444, 5.95889, 3.60558, 
  2.20294, 6.68003, 7.5045, 7.23778, 9.72496, 9.24511, 7.7357, 7.56718, 
  9.35735, 12.0612, 9.39335, 7.61897, 4.42504, 5.30344, 6.76715, 7.29574, 
  2.37094, 6.26673, 7.22273, 10.7688, 11.9598, 10.346, 10.0571, 10.8452, 
  12.109, 11.9974, 7.67068, 10.291, 13.359, 11.5015, 9.96903, 5.44976, 
  1.85815, 0.78936, 3.00597, -1.55573, -7.82983, -7.30225, -6.80859, 
  -6.29809, -3.50606, 3.05057, 1.67047, 1.36792, 3.37618, 4.16687, 
  3.92503, 2.82102, 1.28058, 1.42854, 0.5677, -2.14501, -5.05476, 
  -0.41695, -2.43226, -5.41841, -0.39281, 4.84296, 7.71332, 9.56437, 
  11.0887, 8.18858, 5.8414, 8.03361, 5.6096, 9.51988, 10.3942, 7.05369, 
  4.80606, 4.91824, 8.7106, 7.06899, 8.87901, 9.22051, 6.83539, 5.44371, 
  4.01937, 2.90695, 4.21192, 4.44994, 1.86072, 1.42361, 4.05833, 5.06767, 
  3.9083, 9.2123, 8.6767, 6.64929, 4.55591, 3.16506, 3.36553, 2.66953, 
  4.61189, 2.86679, 3.46284, 6.13807, 5.41028, 4.73737, 7.6795, 4.84524, 
  4.9108, 4.53722, 4.56058, 7.29702, 5.64094, 4.30165, 3.33385, 5.68806, 
  6.04968, 6.52409, 7.5586, 6.0639, 8.24474, 7.06717, 7.5784, 8.51599, 
  6.8743, 6.72083, 7.88874, 11.6331, 10.6445, 10.9836, 9.44053, 9.56508, 
  10.1753, 10.9394, 11.3226, 14.6938, 17.2642, 17.8183, 13.8324, 12.43, 
  11.0775, 11.123, 10.2947, 11.8338, 13.0022, 14.6161, 11.1305, 10.791, 
  12.6827, 11.5605, 10.6563, 12.7656, 11.8701, 12.3721, 11.9769, 10.0403, 
  7.73329, 8.85496, 8.73682, 8.07419, 8.17325, 11.511, 15.145, 15.6102, 
  16.5022, 16.1709, 13.3761, 17.264, 19.687, 20.4323, 21.0252, 21.3723, 
  21.2475, 21.2702, 21.0671, 19.5805, 13.7568, 11.7916, 12.5975, 11.8184, 
  16.3091, 20.1004, 20.0868, 22.3407, 24.2997, 22.7583, 18.9745, 15.9035, 
  16.024, 19.1914, 21.2084, 23.9281, 23.6516, 23.0966, 23.0041, 22.9038, 
  24.5299, 25.7326, 25.4938, 22.6473, 23.7885, 23.8734, 21.9514, 19.2988, 
  20.6958, 18.5028, 16.8761, 20.9387, 18.937, 19.435, 18.4327, 19.8158, 
  20.1101, 21.5998, 21.9932, 24.751, 29.3753, 31.5999, 29.4495, 22.9165, 
  23.2686, 23.2402, 22.9602, 22.2173, 25.9632, 21.593, 20.2721, 21.5224, 
  22.341, 18.6498, 20.1219, 21.8584, 21.6239, 28.0738, 26.4142, 24.7725, 
  21.4159, 17.5402, 17.3853, 21.0012, 22.416, 21.1456, 24.0809, 26.4007, 
  25.5508, 26.0414, 24.3579, 26.1739, 27.2164, 26.8201, 22.8504, 24.2559, 
  24.2006, 24.1552, 23.2342, 21.051, 18.4151, 20.9081, 21.6861, 20.6203, 
  20.4817, 22.5381, 24.1143, 19.6215, 16.6826, 16.2553, 18.6091, 24.0527, 
  21.3717, 19.4247, 18.5746, 18.7393, 18.4001, 22.8524, 22.7096, 20.6259, 
  21.2019, 21.87, 24.6202, 24.5928, 26.9341, 26.6528, 26.7856, 22.2157, 
  19.9978, 21.8183, 21.9206, 22.9321, 23.6834, 21.3737, 20.1084, 19.7119, 
  21.2076, 23.822, 23.8937, 23.4248, 25.1253, 25.6262, 25.5971, 24.2764, 
  22.0123, 22.1025, 19.9025, 17.8464, 17.7661, 16.6241, 17.323, 15.7588, 
  18.1355, 17.9416, 16.9906, 17.0112, 16.7238, 17.8862, 21.1513, 18.0348, 
  14.3367, 15.6564, 13.8713, 13.7946, 11.2834, 11.7613, 11.885, 11.5518, 
  10.1908, 10.3692, 9.66055, 8.75373, 8.11604, 9.20452, 10.0488, 10.4606, 
  9.51533, 11.2533, 11.3637, 9.82202, 9.48856, 9.40134, 9.27895, 9.38484, 
  9.79952, 8.88519, 9.56215, 12.2427, 10.7091, 9.51377, 8.09934, 10.8873, 
  7.91766, 5.03482, 6.79236, 8.02243, 7.74082, 5.97028, 4.93483, 2.84844, 
  2.32958, 2.47728, 0.47363, -0.76344, 0.09932, 4.81134, 8.81348, 
  10.3823, 10.8289, 7.0082, 6.53356, 9.58075, 10.5326, 8.3427, 6.55907, 
  3.43094, 2.91497, 2.75453, 1.51518, 0.21427, 2.24033, 5.84257, 4.55094, 
  1.28517, 0.44241, -1.07106, 1.5077, 3.62158, 8.52128, 8.64829, 10.4853, 
  8.7851, 3.99424, 2.03719, 5.40644, 4.14184, 1.94103, 0.49676, 4.73742, 
  5.46961, 2.09845, 0.8062, 1.13084, 4.14573, 5.41751, 7.99036, 9.54456, 
  7.88317, 7.38799, 4.7107, 1.23217, 1.34194, 3.12594, 2.34215, 3.92943, 
  4.28814, -1.53473, -4.34937, -4.16307, -1.25413, -0.09237, -1.31465, 
  -0.73119, 4.82179, 2.77908, 1.39675, 1.68791, -0.38393, -0.9407, 
  -2.50807, -1.0896, 1.48579, 3.35333, 1.50063, -1.34165, 0.59049, 
  2.07425, 1.62417, -0.45723, -2.24363, 1.2715, 1.70886, 1.32975, 1.4235, 
  0.9802, 1.76901, 2.76971, 3.04066, 0.54875, 0.09775, -1.96935, 
  -2.13567, -1.34802, -0.7473, -0.67197, -1.6728, -1.46587, 3.21076, 
  6.30966, 6.53933, 5.62505, 5.5555, 8.67007, 8.87044, 8.66096, 8.24027, 
  5.36522, 4.60007, 9.09482, 10.9243, 10.1554, 6.20283, 7.00011, 7.76748, 
  10.4434, 11.0272, 7.61685, 4.76488, 8.14287, 9.63522, 8.39318, 4.85702, 
  4.04467, 5.76991, 8.27829, 11.6219, 9.99523, 9.03931, 8.4335, 6.2979, 
  12.9158, 11.189, 8.99983, 8.23214, 10.008, 9.91901, 9.73224, 12.2664, 
  14.6688, 12.9589, 15.8025, 17.6097, 18.3155, 16.456, 11.5136, 11.4097, 
  12.1716, 11.1276, 10.7415, 12.9543, 16.4937, 14.3856, 9.6745, 11.7042, 
  11.2507, 10.6121, 10.2075, 7.9494, 8.26806, 7.21374, 5.15729, 5.86262, 
  11.5133, 9.20826, 8.23779, 10.0843, 10.5073, 8.72061, 10.8578, 10.7059, 
  10.4765, 10.5897, 12.0793, 11.509, 13.7639, 10.9014, 13.0556, 15.2923, 
  16.9558, 10.1238, 8.65529, 11.9741, 15.5228, 18.4538, 18.4287, 18.2232, 
  19.961, 17.3346, 23.6051, 24.8603, 25.0482, 18.7485, 20.2472, 20.9434, 
  20.6219, 15.9234, 17.3461, 21.7219, 23.1824, 25.6746, 27.706, 25.5171, 
  21.6963, 19.7247, 22.6762, 19.4907, 19.0308, 20.3303, 21.4342, 18.2569, 
  18.8592, 23.5841, 22.4464, 25.9043, 22.603, 19.2794, 21.1827, 24.1214, 
  19.5582, 19.7619, 23.9857, 28.3474), .Dim = c(856L, 1L), .Dimnames = 
  list(NULL, "AT [Celcius]"), .Tsp = c(1, 856, 1), class = "ts")
```

Comment: I have this same problem, but I this answer do not solve my problem! I am using a 36 month dataset of water consumption but when I forecast it give me a flat result and I really dont know what I can do

Answer (score 17):

Often [a flat forecast is in fact better than non-trivial ARIMA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125016/1352), just to mention this.

However, your data certainly aren't such a case.

One problem is that you haven't told R that your data are a time series with a frequency of 365. In this case, R can't "on its own" decide that there is seasonality. After all, a long string of data could have all kinds of seasonalities, e.g., with cycle lengths of 7 (daily data with weekly seasonality), 365.25 (daily data with yearly seasonality), 30 (daily data with monthly seasonality), 60, 3600, 24 (I'll let you guess), 11 (yearly sunspot data), etc. You *can't* just "let the algorithm decide". Always specify the `frequency` parameter if your time series might be seasonal.

And even if you have specified the `frequency`, ARIMA has major problems in detecting seasonality with few long cycles in the data - even if the seasonality is "obvious" for a human.

```
library(forecast)

set.seed(1)
temps <- 20+10*sin(2*pi*(1:856)/365)+arima.sim(list(0.8),856,sd=2)

plot(forecast(auto.arima(temps),h=365))
plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(temps,frequency=365)),h=365))
```

[image: no seasonality]

The last two commands actually produce the very same plot, because `auto.arima()` simply doesn't detect the seasonality.

The solution is [to force `auto.arima()` to use a seasonal model, by specifying `D=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37046276/452096):

```
plot(forecast(auto.arima(ts(temps,frequency=365),D=1),h=365))
```

[image: seasonality]

[See also this earlier question.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213201/1352)

---

So. This hopefully addresses one of your questions. Your other question is, to be honest, unclear to me. How do you expect to get a different forecast each time you run your modeling (assuming you re-run it on the same data each time)? ARIMA does not involve any randomization. It is deterministic.

However, you *do* already get predictive distributions and prediction intervals. See the fan plots for the forecasts.

Maybe this earlier question is helpful: [How to incorporate uncertainty of actual historical data into forecast prediction intervals?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285234/1352)

Comment: I am quite sure the question was a duplicate... Duplicate or near-duplicate ARIMA questions proliferate fast here at CV. I think we should try to be more careful instead of producing the same answers to the same questions over and over again.

Comment: Yes, thats probably the problem that its deterministic. But how are the confidence intervals computed? They must be based on predicted values. Any way to extract them from the confidence intervals?

Im also open to any other model which incorporates a stochastic component. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: @RichardHardy: the earlier question I link is close, but not a duplicate. The problem here is that `frequency` is not specified. In this case, `D=1` won't help on its own.

Comment: Careful: you are confusing a [tag:confidence-interval] and a [tag:prediction-interval]. The two are different, and I assume you are interested in the latter. PIs are based on the ARIMA model and on estimated standard errors of the ARIMA coefficients and the innovations variance. If you want the details, look into a technical textbook on ARIMA models. (The non-technical forecasting textbooks won't give you the gory details.) What do you mean by "Any way to extract them from the confidence intervals?"?

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan Kolassa, I actually received a beatiful forecast output that looks like your second plot. 
Including frequency=365 did the trick along with forcing seasonality by setting  D=1 in auto.arima.
Now I only need to get differing forecast trials. Any suggestions how to solve it? Maybe by bootstrapping?

Comment: I am glad I could help. For your remaining question, I still don't understand what you are attempting. I'd suggest you open a new question on this - it's typically best to have one question per post.