# How to decide p P q Q of ARIMA through ACF and PACF?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

(Preface)
My problem is that when I do the time series forecast with `auto.arima()`, it gives me a ARIMA(1,1,1) model which generate a flat forecast line as the below figure.

[image]

My weekly data

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(79L, 83L, 87L, 94L, 110L, 98L, 
102L, 106L, 129L, 113L, 117L, 122L, 124L, 131L, 135L, 139L, 143L, 
162L, 150L, 154L, 158L, 176L, 164L, 167L, 171L, 173L, 24L, 15L, 
18L, 21L, 36L, 27L, 30L, 33L, 50L, 38L, 41L, 45L, 47L, 12L, 3L, 
6L, 9L, 63L, 54L, 57L, 60L, 78L, 66L, 69L, 72L, 74L, 93L, 82L, 
86L, 90L, 109L, 97L, 101L, 105L, 128L, 112L, 116L, 121L, 125L, 
146L, 134L, 138L, 142L, 161L, 149L, 153L, 157L, 172L, 163L, 166L, 
170L, 174L, 23L, 14L, 17L, 20L, 35L, 26L, 29L, 32L, 46L, 37L, 
40L, 44L, 48L, 11L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 62L, 53L, 56L, 59L, 77L, 65L, 
68L, 71L, 75L, 92L, 81L, 85L, 89L, 108L, 96L, 100L, 104L, 123L, 
111L, 115L, 120L, 126L, 145L, 133L, 137L, 141L, 160L, 148L, 152L, 
156L, 168L, 177L, 165L, 169L, 175L, 22L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 34L, 
25L, 28L, 31L, 42L, 51L, 39L, 43L, 49L, 10L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 61L, 
52L, 55L, 58L, 73L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 76L, 91L, 80L, 84L, 88L, 107L, 
95L, 99L, 103L, 118L, 130L, 114L, 119L, 127L, 144L, 132L, 136L, 
140L, 159L, 147L, 151L, 155L), .Label = c("1/13/2019", "1/14/2018", 
"1/15/2017", "1/20/2019", "1/21/2018", "1/22/2017", "1/27/2019", 
"1/28/2018", "1/29/2017", "1/6/2019", "1/7/2018", "1/8/2017", 
"10/14/2018", "10/15/2017", "10/16/2016", "10/21/2018", "10/22/2017", 
"10/23/2016", "10/28/2018", "10/29/2017", "10/30/2016", "10/7/2018", 
"10/8/2017", "10/9/2016", "11/11/2018", "11/12/2017", "11/13/2016", 
"11/18/2018", "11/19/2017", "11/20/2016", "11/25/2018", "11/26/2017", 
"11/27/2016", "11/4/2018", "11/5/2017", "11/6/2016", "12/10/2017", 
"12/11/2016", "12/16/2018", "12/17/2017", "12/18/2016", "12/2/2018", 
"12/23/2018", "12/24/2017", "12/25/2016", "12/3/2017", "12/31/2016", 
"12/31/2017", "12/31/2018", "12/4/2016", "12/9/2018", "2/10/2019", 
"2/11/2018", "2/12/2017", "2/17/2019", "2/18/2018", "2/19/2017", 
"2/24/2019", "2/25/2018", "2/26/2017", "2/3/2019", "2/4/2018", 
"2/5/2017", "3/10/2019", "3/11/2018", "3/12/2017", "3/17/2019", 
"3/18/2018", "3/19/2017", "3/24/2019", "3/25/2018", "3/26/2017", 
"3/3/2019", "3/31/2017", "3/31/2018", "3/31/2019", "3/4/2018", 
"3/5/2017", "4/10/2016", "4/14/2019", "4/15/2018", "4/16/2017", 
"4/17/2016", "4/21/2019", "4/22/2018", "4/23/2017", "4/24/2016", 
"4/28/2019", "4/29/2018", "4/30/2017", "4/7/2019", "4/8/2018", 
"4/9/2017", "5/1/2016", "5/12/2019", "5/13/2018", "5/14/2017", 
"5/15/2016", "5/19/2019", "5/20/2018", "5/21/2017", "5/22/2016", 
"5/26/2019", "5/27/2018", "5/28/2017", "5/29/2016", "5/5/2019", 
"5/6/2018", "5/7/2017", "5/8/2016", "6/10/2018", "6/11/2017", 
"6/12/2016", "6/16/2019", "6/17/2018", "6/18/2017", "6/19/2016", 
"6/2/2019", "6/23/2019", "6/24/2018", "6/25/2017", "6/26/2016", 
"6/3/2018", "6/30/2016", "6/30/2017", "6/30/2018", "6/30/2019", 
"6/4/2017", "6/5/2016", "6/9/2019", "7/10/2016", "7/14/2019", 
"7/15/2018", "7/16/2017", "7/17/2016", "7/21/2019", "7/22/2018", 
"7/23/2017", "7/24/2016", "7/28/2019", "7/29/2018", "7/30/2017", 
"7/31/2016", "7/7/2019", "7/8/2018", "7/9/2017", "8/11/2019", 
"8/12/2018", "8/13/2017", "8/14/2016", "8/18/2019", "8/19/2018", 
"8/20/2017", "8/21/2016", "8/25/2019", "8/26/2018", "8/27/2017", 
"8/28/2016", "8/4/2019", "8/5/2018", "8/6/2017", "8/7/2016", 
"9/10/2017", "9/11/2016", "9/16/2018", "9/17/2017", "9/18/2016", 
"9/2/2018", "9/23/2018", "9/24/2017", "9/25/2016", "9/3/2017", 
"9/30/2016", "9/30/2017", "9/30/2018", "9/4/2016", "9/9/2018"
), class = "factor"), Num = c(9510, 8003, 6247, 7080, 8152, 7540, 
6652, 4968, 5606, 5292, 4834, 5582, 4719, 5621, 6351, 5493, 5871, 
6106, 6056, 4957, 6035, 5306, 5022, 5036, 5051, 5599, 4329, 4143, 
4987, 5109, 4092, 5170, 4820, 19383, 11930, 7526, 8266, 7168, 
4067, 8501, 7687, 7941, 6864, 7510, 7834, 8386, 7151, 6842, 9138, 
8861, 7454, 7907, 7563, 7829, 7332, 7016, 5682, 6896, 6240, 5462, 
4998, 6371, 5697, 5426, 5802, 5823, 6279, 6592, 7291, 7730, 8430, 
8609, 8278, 7750, 8103, 9612, 9912, 8753, 8863, 7670, 7004, 7588, 
6035, 7320, 6093, 27903, 12034, 10530, 13403, 11999, 6754, 10822, 
11888, 10558, 12565, 13973, 11791, 10180, 13456, 17560, 13665, 
13309, 12527, 19347, 11463, 11883, 10257, 12667, 17705, 13286, 
12443, 8937, 12027, 10056, 10083, 10311, 13098, 9520, 10726, 
12888, 11294, 16560, 14914, 15662, 14311, 12948, 11628, 12173, 
11375, 18810, 10467, 9266, 9264, 8612, 12127, 8637, 8142, 28210, 
12627, 9436, 9386, 9318, 9179, 12390, 9605, 11501, 16780, 10471, 
14472, 14173, 16416, 14571.5, 12727, 17780, 15536, 11679, 11729, 
12084, 10514, 10663, 10333, 10807, 10613, 9936, 9586, 12069, 
10740, 8679, 11413, 10151, 10651, 9787, 10987, 12187, 15419, 
13764, 11107)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -177L
))
```

My forecast (forecast next quater)

```
model = auto.arima(data_ts)
autoplot(forecast(model,13))
```

However, I assign D = 1 in `auto.arima()` function according to suggestion from [ARIMA forecast straight line?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286900/arima-forecast-straight-line)
The result is the below figure (seems better)
[image]

I don’t know why I assign D = 1 get a better forecast because I check my data with the function `nsdiffs ()` and I got D = 0.

In this case, I decide to understand how to decide the ARIMA (p, d, q) (P, D, Q) by myself rather than relying on `auto.arima()`.

(Main Question)

I realize that I should decide (p, P) from PACF and (q,  Q) from ACF, but I don’t know how to decide it from the ACF and PACF charts.

For example, I don’t know why MA is 1 rather than 4 in the following resource because I saw ACF cut off at lag 4.
[image]

Source: https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series visually suggests a level shift  suggesting two local means and strong weekly seasonal effects. Since the mean is changing ...the series is de facto non-stationary .

The software you are using probably "GETS CONFUSED" when there are deterministic change points in the mean as the only remedy it has is to incorrectly (in this case ) suggest differencing when other remedies are readily available such as identifying and adjusting for the mean shift .

The cleansed/actual graph provides further insight into the model .[image]

You sent 177 weeks of data starting on 4/10/16 (week 16 of 2016 ). Here is a plot of your data .

[image]

Visually your data suggests D=0 with some arma structure and possible deterministic error variance change structure along with remedies for a few anomalous values and possible seasonal pulses (weekly effects) .

Utilizing the simple acf/pacf of the original series (here [image] and here [image] or any automatic procedure that ignores possible deterministic structure such as level shifts and weekly seasonal patterns  ( as is evident in your data) premises (among other things !) and that there are no pulses , no level/step shifts , no seasonal pulses and no deterministic time trends will be of little value. It is always prudent to know/understand the underlying assumptions of any method/software that you are employing that may go untested. The method of model identification using the acf and pacf that you are using assumes that there are no deterministic patterns in your data OR they have already been treated.

Your data suggests strong anthropomorphic effects where behaviour/activity occurs at specific time in the year.

Using AUTOBOX ( a time series analysis package which I have helped to develop) the following model components wee identified.

1) A pervasive upwards time trend

2) Strong effects for certain weeks of the year

3) One level shift at or around week 75 ( week 38 of 2017)

4) Increased error variance at or around week 72 ( week 35 of 2017)

5) Short term arima structure (1,0,0)(0,0,0)52

Here is a useful model [image] with the TSAY model error variance results here [image] based upon http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html

The acf of the models residuals is here ...suggesting sufficuency [image] .

The Actual/Fit and Forecast is here for the next 156 weeks with 95% prediction limits [image] and forecasts here [image]

In summary your data would be "the worst nightmare" for basic model building software that  tries to just use memory (arima alone) as it contains a number of "complexities" or opportunities that can be readily identified such as Christmas week .

A visual examination of your data supports the conclusions that have been drawn here.

In particular the way you identify using the acf/pacf is to use the conditional acf/pacf after you allowed for latent determninistic effects as suggested by @Adamo in this post [Interrupted Time Series Analysis - ARIMAX for High Frequency Biological Data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/interrupted-time-series-analysis-arimax-for-high-frequency-biological-data/317804#317804) .

Comment: Thank IrishStat for the kind replying! 
(I have upload my data in the questions in R language)
Because I am new to the time series analysis. 
I have a couple of questions about your reply. 
1) " three local means" means there are obvious different patterns in 2017, 2018, 2019 time period?
2) how to tell that my data suggests D=0
3) I don't understand that "The method of model identification using the acf and pacf that you ..."
I know that auto.arima() choose the best ARIMA model according to the minimized AICc and use KPSS test to decide d and D.

Comment: Sorry Irish Stat for the late reply.
I update the data and send you the file right now.